# Changing labels in Partykit

Tags: tree, label, party

In the `partykit` package, I want to round and format the numeric labels on the edges.  How do I do this?
For example, below, I'd like to be able to convert `<11897.65` to `<11,898`.  Rounding to 0 digits after the decimal place and inserting a comma after the thousands.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfLKH.jpg)

Comment: The best way that I've found so far to deal with this is simply to use `rpart.plot`.  (Assuming you've created the tree in `rpart`.)

Answer (score 0):

The labeling of the edges is done by the panel function generated by `edge_simple()`, see `?edge_simple`. You can pass arguments to the edge panel generator using `ep_args`, e.g.,

```
library("partykit")
ct <- ctree(Species ~ ., data = iris)
plot(ct, ep_args = list(digits = 0))
```

[image: ctree]

Inserting a comma to separate thousands is not supported in `edge_simple()`. If you want to have it, you can copy the code of `edge_simple()` and add this type of formatting yourself. However, I would recommend to simply divide the corresponding variable by `1000` which would yield something easily readable.